# ArcGIS 10.0 SQL logs?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Is it possible to have ArcGIS 10.0 dekstop log the SQL it sends to the database (direct connect with Oracle 11gr2)?

I am trying to diagnose some performance issues and would like create some scripts to duplicate what this application is sending to the database. However, you cannot obtain those with a SQL trace (complex datatype).

If not - I will capture the network traffic instead, although that less desirable as it is a rather manual process.